# Is there a way to change the length of dashes for "border: dashed;"?

Tags: css

I'm trying to get this result (i left the red button here just for better perception of dashes):
[image]

But all that comes to my mind is to change border thickness. All that i have for now is:
[image]

and

[image]

But it's not what i'm trying to implement.
And here is my simple CSS:

```
.dashed-wrapper {
    border-bottom: 2px #cccccc dashed;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: You want the border applied only on a single line ?

Comment: @vals, yep, in my case it's `border-bottom`, do you mean this?

Comment: In this case, you can just use a gradient , it will be way easier

Comment: @vals, thanks, i'll read about it

Comment: See this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/nzcowhvw/

Comment: @vals, that's great, thanks a lot! now i know one more interesting css feature